# Ajax Post call is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

It is not returning me FirstName at server. Always returning null. I a unable to understand what it is doing?

Client Side Code

```
    url = '/Home/RegisterByFacebook';
    user = '{ FirstName: "firstName"}';
    var userJson = $.toJSON(user);
  //  console.log(userJson);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: userJson,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'Json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "true") {
                window.location.href = "/search/index";
            }
        }
    });
```

Server Side Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
      public JsonResult RegisterByFacebook(string FirstName)
      {
        return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
```

Inspecting Element is showing me this:

[image]

Comment: your server side code doesn't return any json data

Comment: Please check updated code. I did it but its still doing the same

Comment: The url `/Home/RegisterByFacebook` doesn't exist. That's your problem, not your ajax.

Comment: No please check image i shared, it is sending two calls i don;t know why. in one call it found the method but not in second.
I am not understanding why it is sending two calls

Comment: Could you please try using `Response.Write()` instead of `return` and let me know what happens?

Comment: How can i used response.write in method of type jsonresult?